# Oracle SQL Dev Report Error: ORA-00942 returned ONLY if from CMD

Tags: report, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a few Oracle SQL Developer 'User Defined Reports' that always fail if called from the command line.

The scripts run/query successfully in Oracle Dev.  I can even run the reports successfully by either selecting them in the User Defined Reports folder of Oracle Dev or right clicking and running their HTML version.  But any attempt to run them via cmd returns the below error.

I've ruled out any issues with my queries and now I'm left wondering if there might be some table specific permissions settings that could be blocking me.  If so, what might those be?  If not, any other suggestions on possible resolutions?  Tks!

```
    Command failed:

    java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:494)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:446)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1052)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:537)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:255)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:610)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:253)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:86)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:765)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:921)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1099)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3640)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeInternal(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1384)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3687)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1165)
    at oracle.jdbc.proxy.oracle$1dbtools$1raptor$1proxy$1driver$1oracle$1RaptorProxyOJDBCStatement$2oracle$1jdbc$1internal$1OraclePreparedStatement$$$Proxy.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.dbtools.db.DBUtil$10.call(DBUtil.java:656)
    at oracle.dbtools.db.DBUtil$10.call(DBUtil.java:646)
    at oracle.dbtools.db.DBUtil.assertLock(DBUtil.java:1748)
    at oracle.dbtools.db.DBUtil.executeOracleQuery(DBUtil.java:672)
    at oracle.dbtools.db.OracleUtil.executeQuery(OracleUtil.java:99)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.controls.display.html.TableHtmlGenerator.generateHtml(TableHtmlGenerator.java:88)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.controls.display.DisplayHtml.generateStyleSpecificHtml(DisplayHtml.java:391)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.controls.display.DisplayHtml.generateModelHtml(DisplayHtml.java:325)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.controls.display.DisplayHtml.generateHtml(DisplayHtml.java:261)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.controls.display.DisplayHtml.generate(DisplayHtml.java:202)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.report.headless.ReportsProcessor$GenerateReportTask.doWork(ReportsProcessor.java:101)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.report.headless.ReportsProcessor$GenerateReportTask.doWork(ReportsProcessor.java:39)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTask.call(RaptorTask.java:199)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTaskManager$RaptorFutureTask.run(RaptorTaskManager.java:702)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 Caused by: Error : 942, Position : 335, Sql =
```

Comment: Tell us more about these reports that are failing

Answer (score 0):

Resolved....user error: An incorrect Schema was being referenced in the command line.